# I can't record calls on my Verizon Samsung Galaxy A51

Tags: call-recording

I just bought a Verizon Samsung Galaxy A51 and installed 5 different call recorders but none of them worked. What can I do? I really need to be able to record calls.

Comment: it could be the phone is android 10 and the call recorders are not supporting that

Comment: According to a big computer magazine one of the few good working Android 10 capable apps for call recording is [Cube AR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder) (requires subscription).

Comment: I tried cube acr the free version but it didn't work. Who said that subscribing would fix the problem?